# Core Image Block Customisation

Tags: block-editor

How can I add a new button next to the *Media Library* option in the media panel options of the `Image Block`. I want to be able to customise the Block and edit the template but so far I only get hooks to edit the toolbar and sidebar, nothing for the layout.

[image]

Comment: what would your new button do? What are you trying to do that requires this? Note that the context of why is super important here, especially since there may be valid answers to your question that are completely useless to solving your problem. Also as someone who's tried to mess with that UI in the past, you're going to encounter issues in the future with WP updates as that UI changes and features change. If your goal is to say add support for an image repository/DAM then there are other better ways to do that

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.